# WPF-How to invoke command from inherited window

Tags: wpf

I have stacked with the following situation.
Now, I'm starting a new application on WPF in which I created a generic window to add/edit/remove/consult objects. So the windows have some buttons, a header, a footer, a background color, etc. Then, I inherit this windows to the windows for each object.

So without doing anything, I have most the full window ready.

now in the content area I have add custom contentcontrol to design user input controls screen. 
this custom contentcontrol have some commands which is working fine if I bind the commands to Button control which is in the contentcontrols area but it is not working if i bind to header button which is palced in generic window. I have create all buttons in style of generic window.
any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the Xaml on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your "generic window" has a different data context than the datacontext of the contentcontrol.

To debug binding errors like this it is often helpful to look at the output window.  If the control cannot find the correct binding on the datacontext it will list an error and give some information which may or may not be very helpful.

Also, it would be much easier to help you if you post your code.